# How to include part of the url patterns from an Django app

Tags: django, include-path, url-pattern

I have two django apps with URLs

```
app_name = 'app1'
urlpatterns = [
  path('url1/', ..., name='name1')
  path('<slug:username>/', ..., name='name2')
]
```

and

```
app_name = 'app2'
urlpatterns = [
  path('url2/', ..., name='name3')
  path('<slug:username>/action2/', ..., name='name4')
]
```

This would not work if I include them in the master `urlpatterns` as

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('app1.urls'),
   path('', include('app2.urls'),
]
```

because `url2/` would first match `<slug:username>/` and trigger an error for unknown username.

There are a few potential solutions but none works very well for me:

1. Use non-slug `url2` such as `~url2`. That means all `urls` in `app2` has to start with something like `~` or `^`.
2. Redefine some URLs in the master `urlpatterns` but then I will have to import `views` from the apps and remove urls from the app `urlpattern`.
3. Use regular expression to explicitly exclude some names from the `<slug:username>`. This could work but then any changes in `app2` urlpatterns need to be reflected in `app1`'s `<slug:username> ... exclude certain names`.

It is possible to do something like

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('app1.urls'), # non-user part
   path('', include('app2.urls'), # non-user part
   path('', include('app1.urls'), # user part
   path('', include('app2.urls'), # user part
]
```

so that fixed-name URLs will be matched before `<slug:username>`?

Answer (score 0):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include):

> include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> pattern_list – Iterable of path() and/or re_path() instances.
>
> app_namespace (str) – Application namespace for the URL entries being
> included

You can include specific urls with this method:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(([path('url1/', <YourViewName>)], 'app1'))),
    path('', include(([path('url2/', <YourViewName>)], 'app2'))),
    path('', include(([path('<slug:username>/', <YourViewName>)], 'app1'))),
    path('', include(([path('<slug:username>/action2/', < YourViewName >)], 'app2'))),
]
```

First element of tuple inside include is the list of `path/re_path` instances that you want to include, and the second one is the `app name`.

Comment: This does not appear to be working.. even without splitting my views, simply inserting `    path('', include(([], 'app1')))` before my existing `app1` URLs causes urls in `app1` to stop working. It seems that the namespace needs to be unique.